# Why Rowcommand event of a gridview is not getting fired ?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, c#-4.0, webforms

I am facing a kind of weird problem.

**Problem:**

When I click a link button inside a grid view then **RowCommand** event of a grid view is **getting fired** when deployed on a **localhost** but not when deployed on the **IIS** i.e. client system. I have also tried a link button inside grid view but that's also not getting fired.

**Solution:** (*Temporary*)

When I disabled **ValidateRequest** on the top of the .aspx page. It **worked**.

**What should I do?**
So what can be the possible solution for it? I have googled but nothing good came up.

**Code:**

```
            <asp:GridView ID="gvAppliedWorks" runat="server" OnRowCommand="gvAppliedWorks_RowCommand" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="AppliedWorkID, ContractorID" EmptyDataText="No Data Found"
                CssClass="table table-responsive table-bordered table-striped" OnRowDataBound="gvAppliedWorks_RowDataBound">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Form No">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Literal ID="liFormNo" runat="server" Text='<% #Eval("FormNo")%>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Company Name">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Literal ID="liCompanyName" runat="server" Text='<% #Eval("Name")%>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Financial Bid">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="txtBidAmount" runat="server" CssClass="control-label" Text='<% # string.Format("{0:n2}", Eval("FinancialMoney").ToString())%>' />
                            %
                            <asp:Label ID="ddlBidPer" runat="server" CssClass="control-label" Text='<%# Eval("AboveBelow").ToString() %>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Awarded Percentage">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <div class="pull-left">
                                <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnIsAwarded" Value='<%# Eval("IsAwarded") %>' runat="server" />
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtAwardedBid" Text='<%#Eval("AwardedBid")%>' Style="width: 70px !important;"   runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                            </div>
                            <div class="pull-left" style="margin-top: 7px">
                                &nbsp;  % <%# Eval("AboveBelow").ToString() %>
                            </div>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Remarks">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtRemarks" Text='<%#Eval("Remarks")%>' runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Award Tender">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkAward" runat="server" 
                                CommandArgument='<%# Eval("AppliedWorkID") %>' CommandName="award"
                                CssClass="btn btn-sm btn-danger" Enabled='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("IsBlackList")) == true ? false: true %>'
                                Visible='<%# Convert.ToBoolean( Eval("IsAwarded"))== false? true:false%>' CausesValidation="false" Text="Award"></asp:LinkButton>
                            <ajax:ConfirmButtonExtender ID="cbe" runat="server" DisplayModalPopupID="mpe" TargetControlID="lnkAward">
                            </ajax:ConfirmButtonExtender>
                            <ajax:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpe" runat="server" PopupControlID="pnlPopup" TargetControlID="lnkAward" OkControlID="btnYes"
                                CancelControlID="btnNo" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">
                            </ajax:ModalPopupExtender>
                            <asp:Panel ID="pnlPopup" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup" Style="display: none">
                                <div class="header">
                                    Confirmation
                                </div>
                                <div class="body">
                                    Are you sure to Award this Work?
                                </div>
                                <div class="Popupfooter" align="right">
                                    <asp:Button ID="btnYes" CssClass="btn btn-sm btn-danger" runat="server" Text="Yes" />
                                    <asp:Button ID="btnNo" CssClass="btn btn-sm btn-primary" runat="server" Text="No" />
                                </div>
                            </asp:Panel>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText='Action'>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="btnBlackList" runat="server" OnClick="btnBlackList_Click" Visible='<%# Convert.ToBoolean( Eval("IsAwarded"))== false? true:false%>' Enabled='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("IsBlackList")) == true ? false: true %>' Text='Defective'
                                CssClass="" ToolTip="Blacklist"></asp:LinkButton>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>


**.cs**

   protected void gvAppliedWorks_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

           // GridViewRow gr = ((GridViewRow)((Control)sender).Parent.Parent);
            if (e.CommandName == "award") 
            {
                GridViewRow gr = (GridViewRow)(((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);

                int AppliedWorkID = e.CommandArgument.ToInt32(); //gvAppliedWorks.DataKeys[gr.RowIndex].Value.ToInt32();
                TextBox txtAwardedBid = gr.FindControl("txtAwardedBid") as TextBox;
                TextBox txtRemarks = gr.FindControl("txtRemarks") as TextBox;

                Label txtBid = gr.FindControl("txtBidAmount") as Label;
                Label lblAboveBelow = gr.FindControl("ddlBidPer") as Label;

                string AboveBelow = lblAboveBelow.Text;

                Decimal BidAmount = txtBid.Text.ToDecimal();
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtRemarks.Text))
                {
                    Utility.Msg_Error(this.Master, "Remarks Required!!!");
                    return;
                }
                Decimal AwardedBid = string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtAwardedBid.Text.Trim()) ? 0 : txtAwardedBid.Text.Trim().ToDecimal();
                string Remarks = txtRemarks.Text;

                if (AwardedBid != BidAmount)
                {
                    Utility.Msg_Error(this.Master, "Financial Bid must be equal to Awarded Percentage");
                    return;
                }

                if (ClsTender.IsReceivedSubMainOffice(AppliedWorkID, LoginUserID, AwardedBid, Remarks, BidAmount, AboveBelow))
                {
                    Utility.Msg_Success(this.Master, "Work Awarded Successfully!!!");
                    fill_gvAppliedWorks(labNitNo.Text.Replace("NIT No :", "").ToInt32(), labWorkNo.Text.Replace("Work No :", "").ToInt32());
                }
            }


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Utility.Msg_Error(Master, ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Disabling the ValidateRequest is a VERY BAD IDEA... It sounds like your page is trying to submit what it thinks is potentially dangerous content if setting the "ValidateRequest" to false solves the issue. Is it possible that one of the controls on your page is sending html or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your page is trying to submit what it thinks is potentially dangerous content if setting the `ValidateRequest = false` solves the issue. Is it possible that one of the controls on your page is sending html or something like that?

If one of your controls needs to send HTML then you can overcome this by adding an attribute to your model.

```
 [AllowHtml]
 [Required]
 public string article_content { get; set; }
```

This will allow html to be entered into the control.